# Rest resource API in JIRA Plugin

Tags: api, rest, jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api

Is it possible to create Rest Resource API into JIRA Plugin or have to create separate refapp as below and reference in JIRA plugin project?

https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Developing+a+REST+Service+Plugin#DevelopingaRESTServicePlugin-Step6.Adjustthetestcode

And what will be the url of rest api method to access ?
I mean how it compose to use.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As found,
Yes, it's possible. Follow below tutorial to add REST RESOURCE module in jira project.

https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/REST+Plugin+Module

Below is another ticket related to URL composition for rest resource service:
https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/156650/development-in-jira-plugin-how-to-use-rest-api-in-velocity-template-through-json

Thank You,
Dhaval Soni